# Cifrar ficheros en Java

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy intentando cifrar un fichero y tengo el siguiente código en java, pero al ejecutarlo me peta, el código es el siguiente:

```
public class Prueba {

public static void main(String [] args)
   {

      String comando1 = "-c";
      String comando2 = "-d";

      //COMANDO 1 o COMANDO 2
      if ((comando1.equals(args[0]))||(comando2.equals(args[0]))){    
    //leer clave por teclado
    try{
         InputStreamReader leer_clave = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
         BufferedReader buff_clave = new BufferedReader(leer_clave);
         System.out.print("Escriba una clave: ");
         String clave = buff_clave.readLine();

         //pasar clave a la clase SecretKey
      try{
       SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
       DESKeySpec kspec = new DESKeySpec(clave.getBytes());
       SecretKey ks = skf.generateSecret(kspec);

      //Inicializar el cifrado
         try{
            Cipher cifrado = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

            //Escojo modo cifrado o descifrado segun sea el caso

            if (comando1.equals(args[0])){
               cifrado.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ks);}//MODO CIFRAR
            if (comando2.equals(args[0])){
               cifrado.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ks);}//MODO DESCIFRAR


            //Leer fichero

            InputStream archivo = new FileInputStream( args[1] );
            OutputStream fich_out = new FileOutputStream ( args[2] );

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            byte[] bloque_cifrado;
            String textoCifrado = new String();
            int fin_archivo = -1;
            int leidos;//numero de bytes leidos

            leidos = archivo.read(buffer);

            while( leidos != fin_archivo ) {
               bloque_cifrado = cifrado.update(buffer,0,leidos);
               textoCifrado = textoCifrado + new String(bloque_cifrado,"ISO-8859-1"); 
               leidos = archivo.read(buffer);          
            }

            archivo.close();

            bloque_cifrado = cifrado.doFinal();
            textoCifrado = textoCifrado + new String(bloque_cifrado,"ISO-8859-1");
            //ISO-8859-1 es ISO-Latin-1

            fich_out.write(textoCifrado.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));//escribir fichero

            }
            //Inicializacion de cifrado
            catch(javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {} //Instanciacion DES
            catch(javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {}//metodo doFinal
            catch(javax.crypto.BadPaddingException bpe) {}//metodo doFinal
         }
         //pasar clave a la clase SecretKey
         catch(java.security.InvalidKeyException ike) {}
         catch(java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException ikse) {}
         catch(java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {}
         }
         //leer del teclado la clave como String
         catch(java.io.IOException ioex) {}
      }
   }

   }
```

El error que me sale es:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at pruebas.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:24)**

Haber si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás ejecutando? Porque aparentemente `args` está vacío.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error es por que no estas enviando un argumento a la hora de ejecutar el programa

Ten en cuenta que tu aplicación esta trabajando con el argumento que recibe el método principal entonces al ejecutar tu aplicación tu necesitas enviar dicho argumento.

Si lo ejecutas desde linea de comando puedes enviarlo de la siguiente forma

```
javac Prueba.java
java Prueba -c "esto es un argumento" "esto es otro argumento" esto son 4 argumentos
```

Si lo ejecutas desde algún IDE (eclipse como referencia)

necesitas hacer click derecho > run as > run configurations > arguments
y en el text area ingresar tus argumentos de la siguiente manera

```
-d "esto es un argumento" "esto es otro argumento" esto son 4 argumentos
```

De esta manera ya no te saltara la excepción por otra parte tienes muchos mas errores y debes de tener en cuenta que un objeto del tipo String[] no es un fichero. Si quieres ocupar ficheros utiliza

```
File file = new File("C:/FicheroFoo.txt");
```

Ahora te toca investigar como leer un fichero y como crear un fichero en donde guardes tus datos encriptados